# Rolling back multiple changesets in TFS 2010 in a specific branch

Tags: tfs, branch, rollback, changeset

We have a TFS 2010 server and there are multiple projects are maintained in this server. Changeset numbers are shared across TFS server. In a particular branch I've around 5 changesets and I want to roll back them.

I'm trying to use '**tf rollback /changeset:123~224**' command. My changeset numbers are **123, 145, 148, 201, 222**. In my branch history these changesets are in a sequence and changeset numbers in between these numbers belong to some other projects, which I can't see and access.

When I run the above command does it try to rollback all the changesets across TFS server or only in my branch (rather my current workspace branch)?

Answer (score 1):

Rollbacks are only done in the local copy first.